# Archive rows going to very bottom of sheet. Not right under last row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qxdF.png)**I have the below code working in apps script. It does what it is supposed to as in auto archiving and deleting the rows when a checkbox is selected. The only hiccup is it is archiving the rows to the very bottom of the archive sheet, not right under the last archived row. It skips a lot of blank rows for some reason.**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "ACTIVITY REPORT" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(target);
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Archive' && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 11 
&& (e.value == 'NP CND A ACCEPTED' || e.value == 'NP BACKGROUND')) {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    e.range.offset(0, 16).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Archive' && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 11) 
    {
    let ops = ['NP CND A ACCEPTED', 'NP BACKGROUND', 'HIRED INTERN-SP', 'HIRED SDR- 
  SP', 'HIRED', 'HIRED INTERN', 'HIRED SDR', 'HIRED SDR', 'NP AS', 'NP LDR', 'NP CND A 
  AR', 'NP CND A OFFER', 'NO SHOW', 'NP ORL', 'NP CND A Zoom Int', 'NP CND A 1 FL'];
    if (~ops.indexOf(e.value)) {
      e.range.offset(0, 14).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: I would guess that lastRow is for the Sheet is not the same as it is for column one in `var target = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);`

Comment: @Cooper So, what do I need to change?

Comment: Please provide a screen shot of your sheet.  I'll also provide you with a function that can calculate the height of a column which you can use to get the next row in a column.

Comment: @Cooper I posted a screenshot above. I think it put it as a link. You will see all those empty rows and then information starting row 3983 where it should be starting at 3809. Right now there are blank rows from 3809-3982.

Comment: There are several things that using formulas on  a spreadsheet can interfere with the getLastRow() method and possibly even my getColumnHeight()   That's another reason why I never use cell formulas.  I can see the problem but at this point I cannot discern a solution.  Perhaps you are using an array formula which can cause this sort of difficculty but I can resolve that without look at your spreadsheet and I won't follow links to spreaddsheets.

Comment: @Cooper What is strange is I made a copy of the spreadsheet I am working on and this works fine on it, but puts the rows at the very bottom and skips multiple rows on the sheet I need it to work on. The copy I made is by clicking make a copy. I didn't change anything.